# Web Crawling using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Below is a snippet of my subclass crawlerSub in MainActivity class:

> class crawlerSub extends AsyncTask {
>       private int count = 0;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
>     try {
>         Crawler.crawler("http://www.ipmart.com.my", 10);
>
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>     return null;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
>     File file = null;
>     FileOutputStream fos = null;
>     try {
>         file = this.getFilesDir();
>         fos = this.openFileOutput("visitedLinks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>         for (String link : Crawler.visitedLinks) {
>             fos.write(link.getBytes());
>         }
>     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>         Log.d("Log", e.toString());
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         Log.d("Log", e.toString());
>     } finally {
>         try {
>             fos.close();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             Log.d("Log", e.toString());
>         }
>     }
>     Toast.makeText(ctx, "File saved to " + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
> } }
> ```

My question lies in these 2 lines of code:

> file = this.getFilesDir();
>   fos = this.openFileOutput("visitedLinks", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

when I use "this.getFilesDir()" it gives me "Cannot resolve method error"
How can I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

> class crawlerSub extends AsyncTask {
>       private Context ctx;
>
> public crawlerSub (Context tCtx){
>           ctx = tCtx;
>       }

I passed MainActivity to crawlerSub when calling it, it then allowed me to use the MainActivity context.

Answer (score 0):

use `YourActivity.this.getFilesDir()`. in your code `this` refer asyntask class. but, you want to use functions in activity. to use functions encapsulate class, you should call `ParentClass.this`

Comment: MainActivity.this will not work as well. It will give "MainActivity is not an enclosed class" error

Comment: then, you should send activity as a parameter to asyntask. I thought this asyntask is defined in activity. but, after your comment, it is totally seperate class. so that, you have to send activity instnace to asyntask. calling this.getFilesDir in your case tries to find a function in asyntask